# RealmSwift - transaction completion

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How do I know when a particular transaction has completed?

I want to **run a particular block of code after a transaction is complete**. How can I do this?

I am performing writes in the following war -

```
do {

  try realm.write({
    realm.add(<some object>)
  })
}
catch {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best approach would be to write the method as an extension for `Realm` object.

**For Swift 3+**

```
extension Realm {

    /// Performs actions contained within the given block 
    /// inside a write transaction with completion block.
    ///
    /// - parameter block: write transaction block
    /// - parameter completion: completion executed after transaction block
    func write(transaction block: (Void) -> Void, completion: (Void) -> Void) throws {
        try write(block)
        completion()
    }
}
```

**Swift 2.0**

```
extension Realm {

    /** Performs actions contained within the given block inside a write transaction with
    completion block.

     - parameter block: write transaction block
     - completion: completion executed after transaction block
    */
    func write(@noescape transactionBlock block: Void -> (), completion: Void -> ()) throws {
        do {
            try write(block)
            completion()
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the extension just like a regular `write(_:)` method.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let object = SomeObject()

try! realm.write(
        transactionBlock: {
            realm.add(object)
        },
        completion: {
            print("Write transaction finished")
    })
```

Answer (score 11):

Transactions are executed synchronously. So you can just perform the code right after you execute the transaction.

I would recommend to "force-try" as seen below to abort in case of an error if you don't provide any kind of error handling. Transactions fail recoverable if you run out of disk space. In most situations, you would expect in the code run after a transaction, that your data was persisted, which wouldn't apply in case of an error. Furthermore you don't see any errors in development if you keep the catch path completely empty.

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(<some object>)
}
runMoreCode()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this often does not work correctly when writing is done in one thread, and subsequent reading is done in another thread.